# In C#, how can I set, reset, or define a JsonProperty attribute at runtime?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, integration, typedescriptor

We have a microservice developed in C# which needs to integrate with Salesforce.

We are implementing a new instance of Saleforce and for some stupid reason, someone decided to rename one field from `My_Field__c` to `MyField__c` and they don't want to have any custom fields with any avoidable underscores.  Stupid, but not my choice.

Now I need to integrate a new instance of the microservice to the new instance of Salesforce making the solution different by only a single character, but of course we need to be able to maintain both the original microservice and the new microservice.

In an ideal world, I would just set some value in appSettings and consume this in my declaration of `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "My_Field__c")]`, but of course the attribute requires a compile time constant, so we can't do something so simple.

Creating a custom serializer/deserializer or maintaing a different git branch to remove this one character feels like overkill.

Is there some way I can just set this one attribute dynamically?

(`TypeDescriptor` was suggested as possibly offering a solution, but I can't find details on how I might apply this.)

Comment: Add them both to your model class, plus another property which returns the one which contains a value?

Comment: As above, you can have both in one model, different consumers will ignore property not defined in their json schema

Comment: @Max, I'm not sure what you mean by add them both?  Can I just stack two of the same attribute on the same property?

Comment: @Fabio, If I was communicating direct to Salesforce, _maybe_ the extra property would be ignored, but we have a caching system to bulkify API calls to Salesforce sitting between the two and for security reasons, it won't permit unexpected values...

Comment: Alternative approach is to have two different models and create different instance during runtime before sending data out.

Comment: @BrianKessler added an answer to explain the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to get `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes()` to work with the Type, but this did not work.  As the instance would not exist before deserialization, attempting to use it with an instance was a non-starter.

However, I figured out how to make this work with a Contract Resolver:

```
public static MyModel FromSerializedMyModel(string content, SalesforceFieldNames salesforceFieldNames) =>
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(contents, 
       CreateSettings(salesforceFieldNames));

private static JsonSerializerSettings CreateSettings(SalesforceFieldNames salesforceFieldNames) => new()
        {
            ContractResolver = new MyModelContractResolver(salesforceFieldNames)
        };



class MyModelContractResolver: DefaultContractResolver
    {
        private readonly SalesforceFieldNames _salesforceFieldNames;

        public MyModelContractResolver(SalesforceFieldNames salesforceFieldNames) =>
            _salesforceFieldNames = salesforceFieldNames;

        protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
            Dictionary<string, JsonProperty> propertiesByUnderlyingName = properties.ToDictionary(x => x.UnderlyingName, x => x);
            if (propertiesByUnderlyingName.TryGetValue("MyField", out JsonProperty spvTagProperty))
            {
                spvTagProperty.PropertyName = _salesforceFieldNames.MyField;
            }
            return properties;
        }
    }
```

A bit verbose and otherwise ugly, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

Add two separate properties for the old and new property name and a helper property which returns the one that's been deserialized:

```
public class MyModel
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "My_Field__c")]
   public string MyFieldOld { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "MyField__c")]
   public string MyFieldNew { get; set; }

   [JsonIgnore]
   public string MyField => MyFieldOld ?? MyFieldNew;

}
```

Comment: _but we have a caching system to bulkify API calls to Salesforce sitting between the two and for security reasons, it won't permit unexpected values_

Comment: OP can you elaborate on the caching system? Can you modify it?

Comment: @Max, we have a microservice, also developed in C#.  It is designed facilitate the flow of data both in and out, minimizing the amount it actually needs to know about Salesforce, while also minimizing how much it undermines Salesforce build-in data protection (which it still does compromise, but less than if it completely ignored what fields it is dealing with).  Salesforce itself usually rejects requests regarding data it does not recognize.  I don't think there would be a good way to modify the caching system without creating newer, more profound complications.